# AttributeError: 'Ui' object has no attribute 'ui'

Tags: user-interface, reference, pyqt5, qwidget

I'm having issues referencing my widgets in my second window from my main window. I'm trying to reference my widgets from my FN5 window in the calculator function and then reference that function in my main window. Right now I just have the label reference and trying to change what it says just as a test but every time I try I get the Ui AttributeError

```
class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def FN5(self):
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Fin5Window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def ChooseLine(self):
        SD1 = ["FN5"]
        SD2 = ["FN1", "FN2", "FN3", "FN4"]
        PS1 = ["FN6", "FN7", "FN8", "FN9", "FN10"]
        if SD1.count(self.Line_combobox.currentText()):
            self.start.clicked.connect(self.FN5)
        if SD2.count(self.Line_combobox.currentText()):
            self.start.clicked.connect(self.Retail)
        if PS1.count(self.Line_combobox.currentText()):
            self.start.clicked.connect(self.PS)

   def HourlyCalculator(self):
    
        self.Hourly = self.ui.Label_Hourly_Production
        self.Hourly.setText("Hourly")

    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi("Finishing.ui", self)

        self.start = self.findChild(QPushButton, "Start")

        self.start.clicked.connect(self.ChooseLine)
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.HourlyCalculator)
```

Comment: Please provide a more precise [mre], as right now it's not even clear to which class(es) those methods belong.

Comment: I updated my original post to show more code

Comment: `FN5()` is never called. Do not add just "more code", we need an ***actual*** *minimal, reproducible example*. Your current code will obviously *not* work, as `self.ui` is created in `FN5()`, and since it's never called, it will fail (or crash). Please read more carefully that link and provide what has been requested.

Comment: Sorry I thought I added the ChooseLine function to it last time

Comment: Well, now you've introduced new functions we don't know **anything** about: `self.Retail` and `self.PS`. I believe you've got some confusion with some basic aspects, specifically: how the signal/slot paradigm works and the meaning/usage of classes, instances and their methods and attributes. For instance, `FN5()` is called only when the `start` button is clicked **after** it has been clicked the first time. But since you've also connected its `clicked` signal to `HourlyCalculator`, that function will be called the first time the button is clicked, and at that time `self.ui` doesn't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit difficult to really help you here, as your *final purpose* is not really clear. I strongly suggest you to take your time to understand how signals work, and also consider a better studying on how the whole OOP paradigm works. For instance, `self.ui` is a member of the `Ui` instance, and changing it every time is certainly not a good choice, as it's actually an attribute that should be assigned to the child window. Take a look at https://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/

Comment: Also note that only classes and constants should have capitalized names, functions and variables should **always** have names starting with lower-case letters. The distinction is *very* important for code readability, as *anybody* (including you) should be able to see if an object is a variable/function or a class/constant **at first sight**. Please take your time to carefully read the [Style Guide for Python](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). Finally, `uic.loadUi` already creates attributes based on Qt object names: your button is already accessible as `self.Start`, no need for `findChild()`.